# spring 4 ajax response in 406 not acceptable

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, spring

Application is developed using Spring MVC 4, Hibernate, and jQuery

Below jquery AJAX call is not giving proper response..it is saying 406 error (not acceptable)

I know it is very old and common problem. I have tried:

1. jackson jars
2. in RequestMapping annotation : producers as JSON
3. in RequestMapping annotation : Header as JSON
4. combination of 2 and 3
5. $.post instead of $.ajax (i know it doesn't make difference)
6. My bean object(ValidationResponse) has proper setters and getters
7. URL doesn't have .htm
8. adding accept JSON header like 
   accept: {
                     json: 'application/json',
                     xml: 'application/xml'
               },

jQuery Call in JSP

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "register",    
                data: $('#regForm').serialize(), 
                type: "POST",
                 accept: {
                  json: 'application/json',
                  xml: 'application/xml'
            },
                success: function(result) {  
                // success message
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(XMLHttpRequest.toString());

                }
            });
```

My Controller

LoginController

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register", 
            method   = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody 
    ValidationResponse register(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user") User user, BindingResult result, ModelMap map) {
        ValidationResponse res = new ValidationResponse();

        // Saving into DB logic
        return res; // till here I can see all the values correctly while debugging
    }
```

ValidationResponse bean

```
public class ValidationResponse {

    private String status;
    private ErrorMessage[] errorMessageList;

//getter and setter
}
```

Errormessage bean

```
public class ErrorMessage {

    private String fieldName;
    private String message;
//getter and setters
}
```

app-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/assets/"  />

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:database.properties" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop> 
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.app"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- bind your messages.properties -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"
        id="messageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**Response header**

```
HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1074
Date: Mon, 16 Mar 2015 03:56:02 GMT
```

**Request Header**

```
POST /app/register HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 104
Accept: text/json; text/html; charset=utf-8
Origin: http://localhost:8080
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/json; text/html; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://localhost:8080/app/home
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Let me know if you need any other detail.

Comment: It seems server cannot produce the MIME type which your client accepts. Try to set the accepts property when sending out ajax request.

Comment: tried this also..added in above list

Comment: It is also not working

Comment: "accepts". You miss the "s"

Comment: after that also it is not working.. I used this also.....headers: {          
                  Accept : "text/json; text/html; charset=utf-8",         
                 "Content-Type": "text/json; text/html; charset=utf-8",}

Comment: how about "application/json"?

Comment: ok i will try it also..actually I have tried many things and many combinations of server side and client side code..to make it work..I am totally confuse now... I will try application /json and let you know

Comment: or make sure you added the following dependencies for json
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.1</version>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.1</version>
 </dependency>

Comment: jackson jar is dere..and added application/json..still not working :(

Comment: I created a simple springmvc project and it works. I have no idea why it doesn't on your side. https://github.com/franzwong/codepiece.java/tree/master/spring/springmvc/springmvc002

Comment: My `ValidationResponse object` has another object in this i.e. `ErrorMessage`....is it a problem

Comment: I think you can try to remove them first or add your specific parameters in my simple project.

Comment: It is working now, No need to make changes in content type or header....Just include above 2 jars which you mentioned and jackson-annotation jar..it works.......Thanks a lot franziga to help me out

Comment: I will add an answer, please upvote and close the question. Thanks :)

Comment: it's ok. I just want to make sure other people can get the answer if they encounter the same problem. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following dependencies

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.1</version> 
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```